# Bootstrap css, how to make always visible navbar-toggle?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to add one of those buttons that are shown when on mobile device in order to open the collapsed menu in the navbar, but haven't been able so far, here's the less code and html

```
  .navbar-toggle-always{

    .navbar-toggle;

    @media (min-width: 768px){
      display: block!important;
    }

    .zero-margins;

  }
```

html

```
      <div class="pull-left ">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle-always collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#left" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

upon further inspection I've noticed that the element is not hidden, it's just transparent, for some reason if I add

```
    @media (min-width: 768px){
      display: block!important;
      background-color:pink;
    }
```

i see it fine, but withouth the icon-bar bars or the borders. I'll keep working on it

[image: i can see it!]

and this is how I would like to show it:

[image: Correct]

Comment: what doesn't work?  Do you see the button on mobile?  If yes, does anything happen when you click?

Comment: I want it to be always visible even on desktop, but it's not

Comment: There is code you aren't showing here - such as the normal CSS classes applied to `navbar-toggle-always`.  In bootstrap, the class for the button is `navbar-toggle`, and that isn't shown.

Comment: well, the Less code I've posted inherits .navbar-toggle class and and overrides the media that hides it when over 768px

Comment: i see.  I don't know know much about less, which explains why the above didn't, but now does, make a little more sense.

Comment: Can you post a working example link, bootply (www.bootply.com) maybe?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vyzwfovr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some tests I managed to obtain the desired results:

here's the less code:

```
.navbar-inverse {

  .navbar-toggle-always {
    border-color: @navbar-inverse-toggle-border-color;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      background-color: @navbar-inverse-toggle-hover-bg;
    }
    .icon-bar-always {
      background-color: @navbar-inverse-toggle-icon-bar-bg;
    }
  }
}

.navbar-toggle-always{

  .navbar-toggle;

  @media (min-width: 768px){
    display: block!important;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:1px solid #333333;
  }

  .zero-margins;

  .icon-bar-always {
    .icon-bar;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 1px;
  }

  .icon-bar-always + .icon-bar-always {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
}
```

make sure you have at least 768px on the bottom right panel to see it:

http://jsfiddle.net/vyzwfovr/

Comment: Made a codepen with your code using 3.2.0 and it for whatever reason has the menu icon in the middle.  https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/ZwXgob   Do you happen know why? I guess I will try a live server.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just add `d-block` class to toggler?

```
<button class="navbar-toggler d-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you want to add another one or is it enough to change the existing one. I case, you want to change the existing one, on a default/clean bootstrap install, this show do it:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In a normal bootstrap install, there is this line of css found in their generic css file:

```
.navbar-toggle { display:none; }
```

In order to get the button to always show, in your custom CSS you just need to add this line of code.  If you have your stylesheet applied after theirs, it will overwrite it.

```
.navbar-toggle { display:block; } // the !important isn't necessary
```

Comment: As I've answered above i'm already overriding that, also i still need navbar-toggle to work as it is now

Answer (score 1):

The colors of the toggle and icon-bar are defined along with navbar-default as well as with navbar-inverse. So if you are trying to display them on a custom div, the colors are also removed along with the navbar-default/inverse color scheme.

Add this to your css:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.icon-bar {
    background-color:#333;
}
```

Comment: Do provide a jsfiddle of what you currently have so far so I can help with the dropdown part too

Comment: would be great if you could explain why this works - if it does!

Comment: The colors of the toggle and icon-bar are defined along with navbar-default as well as with navbar-inverse :) So if you are trying to display them on a custom div, the colors are also removed along with the navbar-default/inverse color scheme.

Comment: Hence why I added the icon-bar css falsarella lol The three lines appear once bg-color is defined as I've shown above :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom class to your navbar-toggle, like navbar-toggle-visible and then add this rule to your css

```
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle-visible {
    display: inline;
  }
```

Comment: Not working - tries to display the menu horizontally