# how to make navbar-toggle always visible no matter what window size is in blazor

Tags: navbar, blazor

I tried both [Bootstrap css, how to make always visible navbar-toggle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879905/bootstrap-css-how-to-make-always-visible-navbar-toggle) and [Navbar Toggler Bootstrap 4 - Always Visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979896/navbar-toggler-bootstrap-4-always-visible). But there are not what I want.

Is it possible to make navbar-toggle button always visible with a style overridden regardless what the size of window?

Thanks in advance.

Joon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use the collapse plugin to trigger hidden content elsewhere on the page like this:

```
<div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
      <h4 class="text-white">Collapsed content</h4>
      <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Please chick [bootstrap document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#external-content)

Comment: Thanks for your comments on this. I have tried but it won't work as expected.

Comment: Did you include the right links in the _Host page like bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js, popper.min.js, bootstrap.min.js?

Comment: @JoonwK: "won't work as expected" is not very informative.

Comment: When i go back to work i will be more specific on the failure i got. Thanks all.

Comment: I deleted navmenu.blazor.css and I got result as I want. Thanks a lot.